# Google+ Auto Backup: How to reject non-camera photos?

Tags: google-plus-photos

Google+ Auto Backup service backs up all photos which includes downloaded pics from Web, Facebook, 500px etc. I just want it to backup my cam pics only.

How to do this? I am unable to find any option in Settings for that. Is there a directory flag or other methods to do that?

OS: Android 4.4.2 KitKat

Answer (score 3):

If you have Google's Photos installed, then the following will do the same:
Bring out menu in Photos.

Select On Device.

Uncheck the blue cloud icon for any folder you do not wish to sync with.

Answer (score 1):

There is a setting "Back up local folders" within the Auto-backup settings which when checked will upload any images/videos on your device. If you uncheck this setting it should only backup the camera folder.

Screenshots from Google+ v4.3.1.63038142 running on my Nexus 5:

[image: Main Settings]
[image: Auto-backup settings]

<sup>click image for larger version</sup>

Comment: I am unable to see this option.